# What is the difference between render() and renderStatic() and what should be used when writing a ViewHelper in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

There are several examples for writing a custom ViewHelper and different ways to do things. I have seen examples with render() and with renderStatic (for example in [Developing a Custom ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html)).

In [24 Fluid Tips](https://usetypo3.com/24-fluid-tips.html#c489) there is an explanation, but I don't understand it and it does not make it clear for me why there are 2 functions and what should be used where.

Breaking changes ([Render method arguments on ViewHelpers deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/9.0/Deprecation-81213-RenderMethodArgumentOnViewHelpersDeprecated.html)) and fragmented information in various places makes it difficult to get a clear answer here. Is the example in [Developing a Custom ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/8-Fluid/8-developing-a-custom-viewhelper.html) up to date and best practice?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

▸ **renderStatic()**
First of all, `renderStatic()` is a **static** PHP method. This means, you do not have access to instance attributes, such as `$this->tag`, which is for example required when your ViewHelper class is a subclass of `AbstractTagBasedViewHelper`.

Another drawback of `renderStatic()` is that you can not access child nodes. A child node is for example `<f:then>` in the following example:

```
<f:if condition="{variable}">
<f:then>
...
</f:then>
</f:if>
```

Having said that, `renderStatic()` features the best performance, because it is  called from within compiled Fluid. Therefore, this method should be used if possible.

▸ **render()**
Under certain circumstances, this method is the better choice or has to be used for a specific use case (see explanations above). The logic implemented in a `render()` method is not compiled, which has an impact on output that is cached.

The downside of `render()` is its performance.

▸ **Summary / Additional Notes**

- Use `renderStatic()`, if you can (performance).
- Use `render()`, if you implement an TagBased-ViewHelper (subclass of
  `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractTagBasedViewHelper`).
- Use `render()`, if you need to read child nodes.
- Review the ViewHelpers that are shipped with Fluid (e.g. TYPO3 v9 LTS) as examples.
  (see: `typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers/*`) [[GitHub](https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/tree/master/typo3/sysext/fluid/Classes/ViewHelpers)]

Comment: This is a brilliant answer! Thanks.

Comment: @Michael, Nice to have you on stackoverflow, Hope you remember.