# "Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper" Exception

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x, view-helpers

After updating TYPO3, I get a `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\Exception` "Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper ... Valid arguments are."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Tip: Use rector to make these (and other) conversions! Functions for TYPO3 are available, see

- https://usetypo3.com/using-rector-with-typo3.html

---

This may be due to an extension using functionality that has been dropped. Using only the TYPO3 core, you should not see this error.

In your extension: If you still use the render() method in your ViewHelper class with arguments, you may want to replace this:

---

before:

```php
public function render(Mail $mail, $type = 'web', $function = 'createAction')
```

---

after:

```php
public function initializeArguments()
{
    parent::initializeArguments();

    $this->registerArgument('mail', Mail::class, 'Mail', true);
    $this->registerArgument('type', 'string', 'type: web | mail', false, 'web');
    $this->registerArgument('function', 'string', 'function: createAction | senderMail | receiverMail', false, 'createAction');
}

public function render()
{
    $mail = $this->arguments['mail'];
    $type = $this->arguments['type'] ?? 'web';
    // ...  

}
```

---

Additionally,

- if there is no need to use **render()** (e.g. unless you need to access $this variables), you may want to switch to **renderStatic()** for performance reasons (see also this other Stack Overflow answer ["What is the difference between render() and renderStatic() ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531152/what-is-the-difference-between-render-and-renderstatic-and-what-should-be-us) for clarification)
- inherit from classes in `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper` instead of `TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper`:

```php
// use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
use TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper;
```

---

Documentation:

- [Developing a Custom ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Fluid/DevelopCustomViewhelper.html)

Changelogs:

- [Breaking: #82414 - CMS ViewHelper base classes removed](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Breaking-82414-RemoveCMSBaseViewHelperClasses.html) (>= TYPO3 9.0)
- [Deprecation: #81213 - Render method arguments on ViewHelpers deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.0/Deprecation-81213-RenderMethodArgumentOnViewHelpersDeprecated.html) (>= TYPO3 9.0)
- [Breaking: #87193 - Deprecated functionality removed](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/10.0/Breaking-87193-DeprecatedFunctionalityRemoved.html) (>= TYPO3 10.0)

Answer (score 0):

You are using other extension that makes this error, for example: https://github.com/lochmueller/calendarize/issues/280

If you have a parameters in a ViewHelper, you send them as arguments from Fluid Template. In TYPO3 this error throws when in `render()` function not have comments about parameters. You have to include them.

Example:

```
<?php

namespace VENDOR\ExtensionName\ViewHelpers;

class ExampleViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper
{

 /**
  * 
  * @param int $foo
  * @return boolean
  */
 public function render($foo) {
     //function render lines    
     return $bar_boolean;
 }
}
```