# Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper

Tags: typo3, fluid, view-helpers

I upgraded a website from TYPO3 v7 to v9 and now I get the following error:

> *Undeclared arguments passed to ViewHelper \ViewHelpers\MyViewHelper: value, list. Valid arguments are: [...]*

My current ViewHelper looks as follows:

```
<?php

namespace VP\News\ViewHelpers;

/**
* @package TYPO3
* @subpackage Fluid
*/

class InListViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper  {

/**
* @param mixed $value value
* @param mixed $list list
* @return boolean
*/

public function render($value, $list) {
    if (!is_array($list)) {
        $list = str_replace(' ', '', $list);
        $list = explode(',', $list);
    }
    return in_array($value, $list);
}
}
```

Comment: Similar question exists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274811/undeclared-arguments-passed-to-viewhelper-exception/57274812

Answer (score 2):

Some things have changed between v7 and v9 ViewHelpers in [TYPO3 Fluid](https://github.com/typo3/fluid).

➊ You should extend from the abstract class `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper`.
➋ You have to register the arguments you pass to the ViewHelper.
➌ Your ViewHelper looks more like a *Condition-ViewHelper* than an *Abstract-ViewHelper*.

The first point is self-explanatory. Simply change the name of the base class (the fully qualified class name). For the second point, you can use an additional method `initializeArguments()`. For example:

```php
public function initializeArguments(): void
{
  parent::initializeArguments();
  $this->registerArgument('value', 'type', 'description');
  ...
}
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/typo3-extbase-book/simpleblog/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/DummyTextViewHelper.php).

However, your ViewHelper seems to check a condition ("*is this element in a list?*", "*then...*", "*else...*"). Therefore, it might be better to implement a *Condition-ViewHelper*.

This type of ViewHelper extends the class `TYPO3Fluid\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper` and evaluates a condition using a method `verdict()` instead of `render()` or `renderStatic()`.

You can find an example of a simple *Condition-ViewHelper* [here](https://github.com/typo3-extbase-book/simpleblog/blob/master/Classes/ViewHelpers/IsFrontendViewHelper.php).